# Compensating for rotation when accelerometer not at center of mass?

Tags: attitude-determination-and-control, accelerometers

It's dawned on me that the accelerometers of a rocket will generally not be at the center of mass. In part because the center of mass varies widely as fuel is consumed.

This means the acceleration (or dv) measurement will include undesirable terms from angular velocity and angular acceleration about the center of mass.

"Undesirable" because those terms say nothing about the translational motion of the center of mass, which is the thing you'd want to measure with an accelerometer. You already have gyros to track rotation.

So it seems that the reading from an accelerometer will generally need to be corrected for the accelerometer's offset from the center of mass.

Is this done in practice? If so, is the correction updated continuously to reflect the latest estimate of the center of mass?

Comment: It's a great point! In fact signals from several distributed accelerometers could be used as a makeshift gyro. If acceleration vectors from devices on opposite sides of a craft both point *outwards*, then it's either in the process of rapid disassembly or it's spinning.

Comment: @uhoh A third possibility for different sensed accelerations from multiple accelerometers is gravity gradient. This requires either a very large spacecraft or very sensitive accelerometers. [GOCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_Field_and_Steady-State_Ocean_Circulation_Explorer) used six extremely sensitive accelerometers to map the Earth's gravitational field.

Comment: Yes, and the apollo LM familiarization manual describes the corrections used in some detail.

Comment: Any links to the LM familiarization manual that I could look at? Thanks for mentioning it, @Innovine!

Comment: @DavidHammen Hmmm... really good point! [Which nD accelerometer symmetric configurations on a cubical LEO spacecraft can serve as a makeshift 3D gyro resolving tumbling from tidal forces?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/52329/12102)

Comment: I've searched through most of the LM familiarization manual, but still, no reference to CM corrections made to the accelerometer readings. Nor would it seem to be in scope, given that the manual is a broad, general overview of everything about the Apollo spacecraft, and that technical detail on things like algorithms is scarce compared to other manuals. Are you sure this is the right manual, @Innovine?

Comment: @user39728_i_said_user_39728_i_ do you have any thoughts on [Get rid of the old ADCS tag and either merge with attitude-control or attitude-determination-and-control?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1800/12102)

Comment: hmm, I'm sorry, I thought it was in that one. I've definitely seen this mentioned in one of the official apollo pdf manuals for the LM, but I don't know exactly which one as it wasn't something I was paying attention to at the time. From memory, it accounted for the position of the accelerometer, but not a shifting center of mass..

Comment: @uhoh: here is a paper mentioned elsewhere that shows how to do just that---to calculate angular velocity using only accelerometers (arrays of them, really). The paper: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4208239/

Comment: @user39728_i_said_user_39728_i_ excellent! If you can find a way to work that paper into a question or an answer post somewhere then all the better!

Comment: @user39728_i_said_user_39728_i_ oh! Can't that be used to answer [Which nD accelerometer symmetric configurations on a cubical LEO spacecraft can serve as a makeshift 3D gyro resolving tumbling from tidal forces?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/52329/12102)

Comment: Ha ha. It seems like it could! I'm pathetically jammed for weeks and probably can't write up an answer until I'm finished, though :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to estimate the position of the vehicle's center of mass, along with its mass and inertia tensor. These may or may not be part of your Kalman filter estimated state.  There's no clear cut right answer on how to do this, but you do need to do this.