# Which nD accelerometer symmetric configurations on a cubical LEO spacecraft can serve as a makeshift 3D gyro resolving tumbling from tidal forces?

Tags: attitude-determination-and-control, acceleration, gyroscope, accelerometers, rate-gyros

As they often do [@DavidHammen's comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/52306/#comment172739_52306) has got me thinking about the following question, which is a *mathematical exercise* rather than a realistic scenario.

---

On a hypothetical large cubical spacecraft the gyros used for attitude rotation measurement have all stopped working and the star cameras only work *occasionally*.

In between star camera fixes, we must rely on an array of peripheral accelerometers distributed symmetrically around the cube's surface to provide acceleration data that we can integrate to update a calculated instantaneous attitude.

But luckily there are a number of very high quality accelerometers around the periphery of the cube. They have low offsets, stable gains and are quite linear.

Could they *mathematically resolve* slow, random 3D tumbling (due to awkward mass distributions and sloshing fuel) from the inevitable gravity gradient/tidal forces the cube experiences?

Consider the following six cases:

```
case  number   locations     axes per  orientations  total axes
 A       6    face centers      1         radial          6
 B       8      corners         1         radial          8
 C       6    face centers      2       tangential       12 
 D       8      corners         2       tangential       16
 E       6    face centers      3           3D           18
 F       8      corners         3           3D           24
```

**Question(s):**

1. Which would be able to mathematically simultaneously resolve slow 3D tumbling from gravity gradient/tidal forces?
2. Would all be able to simultaneously *mathematically* resolve a center-of-mass acceleration due to a weak propulsive force (e.g. aerodynamic drag) without confusing/confounding/mixing it with the the other two effects?

**note:** if there's a general solution or set of rules expressible that would allow us to determine the answer for all these cases plus others (e.g. 2 axes with one radial and one tangential) then it's not necessary to give six answers. The primary goal of the table is to give an idea of how one might have anywhere from 8 to 24 acceleration values based on symmetry points of a cube and n = 1, 2 and 3D axes per accelerometer.

Comment: This is my favorite question right now. I'm convinced you can do this, but it would be nice to know for sure.

Comment: Do the spacecraft's GPS receivers still work? If they do, that plus a model of the Earth's gravitational field will give a good idea of the expected gravity gradient. Is the vehicle subject to significant magical external torques? If not, the fact that star sightings are available some of the time will enable a decent (not necessarily great) nav expert to write a Kalman filter that fills in the missing parts. I suspect that six accelerometers organized in three orthogonal pairs would suffice.

Comment: @DavidHammen for the purposes of our gedankenexercise let's make Earth's field a monopole and the orbit circular, and not use GPS. But since it would be a fun challenge,  certainly (masochistic) answers which also addressed an elliptical orbit around an oblate planet would be welcome :-)